# Probability of width of a confidence interval being less than a value

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Let independent random variables $X1, X2,…, Xn$ be identically normally distributed with unknown mean $μ$ and unknown variance $σ^2$:

(a) Determine the 95% confidence interval for μ, $n=51$,  $\bar{x}=10$,  $S^2 = 0.8$ where:

$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n}^n x_i$ and $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$

(b) Suppose $\sigma^2=0.5$. Find the probability that the width of the 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is $\leq$ 0.3.

---

My idea so far:

Boundaries: $[10-0.15, 10+0.15] = [9.85,10.15]$

$P(9.85 \leq X \leq 10.15 |\mu=10,\sigma^2=0.5) \approx 0.168$

However, I find this probability intuitively low since the width of the 95% CI according to my workings is:

$10 \pm 1.96\sqrt{0.5/51} = 10 \pm0.194$ 
which gives a width of:

$2*0.194=0.388$

Thus, intuitively I thought that that the probability would be way higher.

Am I having a faulty approach or is it just my intuition that is wrong?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have an estimate of the standard deviation ($S^2=0.8$), from which you can directly compute your CI (for what probability? 0.95? Or is this number what you are actually looking for?). So the CI is either wider than 0.3 or narrower. There is no probability involved on the CI width any more.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica You're totally right, I've probably misinterpreted the question, I've updated it with the actual question aswell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

a)  Confidence intervals look like

$$ \hat{\mu} \pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\dfrac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$$

So your interval should me $ 10 + 1.96 \sqrt{\dfrac{0.8}{51}}$

b) Note that the width of the interval is a function of the size of the sample standard deviation.  The length is

$$ 2 z_{1-\alpha/2}\dfrac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$$

All but the $S$ are fixed quantities.  Note that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot, please check my updated answer.

Comment: You can verify you answer by using simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after the feedback I've tried this for (b):

width $= 2*z_{0.025}*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} < 0.3 \implies S < \frac{0.3 \sqrt{n}}{2*1.96} = 0.547$

And thus we want the probability:

$P(S_x< 0.547 |\sigma^2=0.5) \Leftrightarrow$

$P(S_x^2< 0.3 |\sigma^2=0.5) \Leftrightarrow$

$P(\frac{50*S_x^2}{0.5}< \frac{50*0.3}{0.5}) \Leftrightarrow$

$P(\chi_{50}^2 < 30) \approx 0.0112 $

Is this a correct approach?

Thanks in advance!